# How to disable users from being able to view app through regular browsers in express / electron app

Tags: node.js, angular, express, electron

I have an express server that serves my angular front end at http://localhost:9000

I'm using electron as a desktop client.

I want to force users to view the application through electron and only through electron.  I don't want users to have the ability to browser the application through any other browser.

Is there any way to disable the ability to access the app through a regular browser?

I've attempted to find information regarding this but have come up short.

Comment: Sounds like something that could be extrmely tricky if not impossible. Rethink your approach considering that any regular http traffic can be crafted using various tools, including http debuggers, the cURL and other tools.

Comment: Yeah I think for my specific circumstances, zGeek's answer will work.  However I'm sure you're right about other tools potentially being able to gain access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: This can only be done on the client side

You can check if the `window.process` object exists.

`if (window.process && window.process !== undefined) { 
   // Likely electron 
}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related, but is it possible for you not to use localhost? I found that after building angular parts (with `ng run build`) and referencing them in electron's main.js there was no need for local server to be running (but so far I only stuffed angular's quickstart into electron shell)

Comment: In my specific situation I'm connecting multiple devices over a local network.  I'm using express to run on a port that hosts a socket.io server so that I can utilize real time data sharing between devices.  If you know a better way to handle this, I'm open to suggestions as I'm now debating the need for express.  But by using express, that is why I have electron point to localhost